# Audio not working (after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa

After upgrading it, dummy output is been shown in my sound settings.
Also, no Alsa mixer is there in terminal. Though, I've different soundcards and all other stuff...
But still not working, I've tried many "superuser commands" and no result.
Please help me if anyone knows how to fix this.